# How to query for consecutive days with null records?

Tags: sql, db2

I am currently working on a task that queries for a certain type of record. If it is null or less than 1 for the current date an email sends out. That part is pretty straight forward. Now a requirement has been added to get a count for how many days consecutively this has been happening.

If there are no records in the table, there are no dates to check on, so I'm not entirely sure what to do.

If I query on multiple dates then it destroys the code which is built upon emailing on a null result.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why would you change the existing code if you got an additional requirement? You can build new code for the new requirement and let the old code do its work.... Please provide more information.